# Custom delegate is applied even if the feature is deactivated

Tags: 2010, development, feature, feature-activation, delegate-control

I have a question regarding a feature.

Situation:
I have a feature that is farm scoped, with this feature I deploy a delegate control (xml file), this file refers to cs code. 
So I've added that file to the solution I deploy the solution, I set the solution NOT to automatically activate. So when I deployed the solution it is deactivated, BUT the I do see that the my custom delegate control is used instead.

It is strange, no matter if the feature activated or not the control is used how it comes?

I thought that hen you deactivate the feature the files that are deployed with the feature should not be active or something, or am I wrong?

Or what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Is the XML file a module in Visual Studio?

Comment: yes it is in VS

Comment: and no it is not module, ive added it a an empty element